# comparing DateField with timezone.now().date()

Tags: django, django-models, timezone, datefield

I am trying to compare DateFIeld with timezone.now().date() but its not giving the desired output:

models.py:

```
class Holiday_List(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
holi_day=models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
def __str__(self):
    return '{}---{}'.format(self.name, self.holi_day)
```

admin.py:

```
def refresh():
flag=0
din=Holiday_List.objects.all()
for aaj in din:
    if aaj.holi_day==timezone.now().date():
        flag=1
        break;
if(flag==0):
    # some code to be executed
```

I have objects with today's date in the Holiday_List but still the flag value is not being set to 1 and the code gets executed after calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter this with:

```
def refresh():
    flag = Holiday_List.objects.filter(
        holi_day=timezone.now().date()
    ).exists()
    if not flag:
        # …
```

Note that `flag` is `True` in case there *exist* `Holiday_List` objects with `holi_day` as today, and thus `False` otherwise. The `if not flag` will thus be triggered if today is *not* a holiday.